# Highlighter not work when i used dangerouslySetInnerHTML inside Highlighter tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

when i used dangerouslySetInnerHTML inside react-highlighter, then highlight class wont work.

```
<Highlight search={searchQuery}
className={Styles.body_highlighter}
innerHTML={true}
matchStyle={{ background: '#fff466', padding: '0px' }}>
<div className={Styles.body_highlighter}
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.body }} />
</Highlight>
```

table is shown but yellow highlight on searched word dont showing.
image link -> https://ibb.co/7C80pTG

but when i remove dangerouslySetInnerHTML from the code, then table does not shows.

```
<Highlight search={searchQuery}
className={Styles.body_highlighter}
innerHTML={true}
matchStyle={{ background: '#fff466', padding: '0px' }}>
{item.body} 
</Highlight>
```

table is not  shown  yellow highlight on searched word  showing.

image link-> https://ibb.co/25W8VmW

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you mistakenly uploaded the second image for first one.
2. If use use fetch api to fetch html text, use items.text() in the promise handler.

   const item = await fetch(url).then( data => data.text() ).then(text => {
   return text;
   });

Then use this.

```
<div
   className={Styles.body_highlighter}
   dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item}}
/>
```